# My Reset password link for my flask web app is not redirecting and updating the password

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, token, reset-password

So I have this function to reset the user password through email, everything works fine (Almost)
The email is send with the token and I am able to open the link which redirects me to the page to type in my new password, but when I do and submit.
It redirects me to a 404 page I created to go to when the user tries to go to an incorect page

Here is my relevant code

```
def send_reset_email(user):
    token = user.get_reset_token().decode('utf-8')  # Decode bytes to string
    print("Reset Token:", token)
    msg = Message('Password Reset Request', sender='noreply@demo.com', recipients=[user.email])
    msg.body = f'''
    To reset your password, visit the following link:
    {url_for('reset_token', token=token, _external=True)}

    If you did not make this request, please ignore this email and consider changing your email and password.
    '''
    mail.send(msg)

@app.route("/reset_password", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RequestResetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        send_reset_email(user)
        flash('Reset password email has been send', 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    return render_template('reset_request.html', title='Reset Password', form=form)

@app.route("/reset_password/<token>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_token(token):
    print( url_for('signin') )
    print("Reset Token Route Triggered")
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        print('redirecting you to index')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    user = User.verify_reset_token(token)
    if user is None:
        print('The user value was none')
        flash('That is an invalid or expired token', 'warning')
        return redirect(url_for('reset_request'))
    form = ResetPasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user.password = hashed_password
        print(f"new password is {user.password}")
        db.session.commit()
        print("Password has been committed")
        flash(f'Your password has been updated', 'success')
        print("Redirecting you now to sign in")
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    return render_template('reset_token.html', title='Reset Password', form=form)
```

User Model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    # Manual Table name choice
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(130), nullable=False)

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).encode('utf-8')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)

    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname,email,password):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
```

and finally my fors to reset password and request reset form

```
class RequestResetForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email()])
    submit = SubmitField('Request Password Reset')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is None:
            raise ValidationError("There is no account with this email.")


class ResetPasswordForm(FlaskForm):
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=200)])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=200), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Reset Password')
```

Would highly appreciate anyone's help here

Thank you!

I believe my issue is here in my reset_token function as it is supposed to commits the updated password tot he db and then redirects the user to the sign in page but it is not doing so

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: did you run code in terminal/console to see error messages?

Comment: after resetting it executes `return redirect(url_for('signin'))` - do you have this function `signin` ?

Comment: so yes I tried print debugging, and I came with that the reset_request fun gets requested but does not finish at all, and also I have this as my signin function
and yes I have the function sign in

Comment: also I do not see any error messages, I get redirected to my 404 page that gets to it when there is an invalid URL

Comment: maybe first you should check `print( url_for('signin') )` to see what you really get. And you should check if you this url works in browser. Maybe it needs some extra parameters to execute correct function. You can also remove your own page `404` to see error message from flask. And you can run it with `app.debug = True`.

Comment: So I updated my "reset_token" function and added a bunch of print statements.
In my console I only get two outputs

/signin. (from the "print( url_for('signin') )")
Reset Token Route Triggered (from the "print("Reset Token Route Triggered")")

So basically the function gets called but nothing else is printed or called from what I can see, any idea were to go next ?